# Bootstrap requires JQuery (using Express with Parse)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, express, parse-platform

I am working on writing a small website. I am hosting the site with [Parse](https://parse.com/) and using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). The top of the app.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var _ = require('underscore');
var jquery = require('cloud/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
var bootstrap = require('cloud/libs/bootstrap.min.js');
```

When I go to deploy (`parse deploy`) the app, it comes back with the following error:

```
Uploading source files
Finished uploading files
Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at libs/bootstrap.min.js:6:37
    at app.js:6:17
    at main.js:1:1
```

I cannot figure out how to include Bootstrap and JQuery in my app without getting this error. I've followed the setup instructions that Parse has [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp). I am serving the files up myself.

Does anyone know how to include Bootstrap and JQuery in this type of web app?

I am new to this, so if you have any clarifying questions please ask kindly.

Comment: Please use the twitter-bootstrap tag for this question as the bootstrap tag means something else.

Comment: You should be require()ing either the individual Bootstrap plugins or [`/dist/js/npm.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/npm.js) instead of `bootstrap.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was serving it up myself I moved the Bootstrap and JQuery files into the public folder and included these tags in my `_header.ejs`.

```
<script src="/bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My mistake was not putting the bootstrap files in the public folder.

I am also looking into using [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) or [Hosted Bootstrap](http://hostedbootstrap.com/). Unless of course it is better to serve them up statically?

Comment: I'm thinking about using Parse as the backend for my web site that will use Bootstrap for the front end.  What has been your experience since you got it working and what advice would you have for me doing it from the ground up?